# My code ignores subsequent if and while conditions

Tags: java

I am devising a project to compare user results to standard results. My algorithm wont run exactly the way I wish it would (scoring system). The problem with my code is that it simply will not run in the way I wish it would. It will only read from the first "while" & "if" condition. It simply doesn't recognize the other conditions. The age and score will be provided from an external source, therefore this is just an algorithm/scoring system for the tool.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class algorithm_tester {

    int score;

    int age;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int score = 0;
        int age = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //User Inputs Score
        System.out.print("Enter Your Score: ");
        int myscore = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Score entered = " + myscore);

        //User Inputs Age
        System.out.print("Enter Your Age: ");
        int myAge = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Age entered = " + myAge);

        while (age < 30) {

            if (score < 15) {
                System.out.println("Your Score Is Slightly Abnormal For Your Age.");
            } else if (score < 10) {
                System.out.println("Your Results Are Rather Low. Therefore, We Recommend You Seek Medical Advice.");
            } else if (score < 8) {
                System.out.println("Your Results Suggest Severe Cognitive Impairment. You Must Seek Medical Attention Immediately.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Well Done! You Scored Very Well.");
            }

            while (age < 40) {

                if (score < 14) {
                    System.out.println("Your Results Are Slightly Abnormal For Your Age.");
                } else if (score < 10) {
                    System.out.println("We Recommend You Seek Medical Advice As Your Results Are Quite Low.");
                } else if (score < 7) {
                    System.out.println("Your Score Is Very Low. We Believe You May Have Experienced Majoe Cognitive Impairment. We Recommend You Seek Immediate Medical Attention.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Well Done! You Have Shown No Evidence Cognitive Impairment");
                }

                while (age < 60) {

                    if (score < 12) {
                        System.out.println("Your Results Are Slightly Abnormal For Your Age.");
                    } else if (score < 9) {
                        System.out.println("Your Score is Very Low. We Believe This Is Due To Minor Cognitive impairment. We Recommend You Seek Medical Advice.");
                    } else if (score < 6) {
                        System.out.println("Your Results Have Led Us to Believe You Have Suffered Severe Cognitive Impairment. You Must Seek Medical Attention Immediately.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Congratulations! Your Results Were Excellent. You Have Shown No Evidence Of Cognitive Impairment");
                    }

                    while (age < 80) {

                        if (score < 10) {
                            System.out.println("Your Results Are Slightly Abnormal For Your Age.");
                        } else if (score < 7) {
                            System.out.println("Your Score is Very Low. We Believe This Is Due To Minor Cognitive impairment. We Recommend You Seek Medical Advice.");
                        } else if (score < 5) {
                            System.out.println("Your Results Have Led Us to Believe You Have Suffered Severe Cognitive Impairment. You Must Seek Medical Attention Immediately.");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Congratulations! Your Results Were Excellent. You Have Shown No Evidence Of Cognitive Impairment");
                        }

                        while (age > 80) {

                            if (score < 10) {
                                System.out.println("Your Results Are Slightly Abnormal For Your Age.");
                            } else if (score < 6) {
                                System.out.println("Your Score is Very Low. We Believe This Is Due To Minor Cognitive impairment. We Recommend You Seek Medical Advice.");
                            } else if (score < 4) {
                                System.out.println("Your Results Have Led Us to Believe You Have Suffered Severe Cognitive Impairment. You Must Seek Medical Attention Immediately.");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Congratulations! Your Results Were Excellent. You Have Shown No Evidence Of Cognitive Impairment");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your indented code (to format it, first select it and either press `Ctrl+K` or use `{}` icon from editors menu).

Comment: Why are you using `while` loops here? That fundamentally doesn't make sense for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also, you never actually get user input for the age, you just hardcode it to 0, which presumably isn't what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Please format your code for human readability, i.e. indent it to show the code structure, and remove all those extraneous blank lines. Personally, I refuse to look at bad code like this, so good luck.

Comment: BTW `else if(condition){..}` sections should be either more **general** then previous conditions or unrelated to them at all. For instance code like `if(x<10){ foo(); } else if (x<5){ bar(); }` will never let you call `bar()` method because each `x` which can pass `x<5` test also passes `x<10` condition which is checked earlier, so it will call `foo()`.

Comment: I fixed your indentation. In the future let your editor do it for you, so you will see real levels of indentation which your code describes. This should let you see some of problems with scope easier.

Answer (score 5):

That's because your `while` loops are infinite loops, and because you should reverse the order of your `if` statements. You never get user input inside any of your loops, so there's no way for the values to change. Once `age < 30`, for example, `age` will *always* be less than 30, so this loop will never end and it'll never run any other part of your program other than what's inside that particular `while` loop.

For that matter, you're currently hardcoding `age` and `score` to 0 and never changing them - I assume that you'll want to get user input or something here.

A `while` loop fundamentally doesn't make sense for what you're trying to achieve, though. You should actually use nested `if` statements, like this:

```
if (age < 30) {
   if (score < 8) {
      // ...
   }
   else if (score < 10) {
      // ...
   }
   // Etc.
}
else if (age < 40) {
   // ...
}
else if (age < 60) {
   // ...
}
// Etc.
```

If you want to repeat the entire program until the user enters a particular value, for example, *then* it would make sense to put the entire program inside a `while` loop that checks the value of the user input.

Also note that I reversed the direction of the nested `if` statements. If the score is less than 8, it'll also be less than 10 and less than 15, so you want to check to see if it's less than 8 first.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking input for "myscore" and "myage" variables while your if and while conditions are totally based on the different variable that is "age" and "score" which is zero as you have assigned it so it always goes to the first if and while and your algorithm is not working
put age=myage //after taking the input
and
score =myscore//after the input of score